# Execute command when a binding updates?

Tags: wpf, binding, command

Is it possible to have a command execute when a binding is triggered? e.g. given:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someConvertor}">
    <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
    <Binding Path="LastName"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someConvertor}" TriggerCommand="{Binding SomeCommand}">
    <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
    <Binding Path="LastName"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Such that whenever `FirstName` or `LastName` changes, the 'SomeCommand' is executed?

The problem I see is that as that markupextension doesn't derive from `DependencyObject`, so I'm not sure how I would get the behavior I want

Basically I have some code that doesnt play nicely with bindings, and something like this would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your datasource class.

[This guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) provides complete documentation on how to do this.

...but in summary, lets assume you're binding to a list of *people* with the properties FirstName and LastName

```
Public Class People
Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
private _firstName as String
private _lastName as String

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Property FirstName As String
Get
Return _firstName
End Get
Set(value As String)
_firstName = value
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"))
End Set
End Property

Public Property LastName As String
Get
Return _lastName
End Get
Set(value As String)
_lastName = value
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"))
End Set
End Property
```

The PropertyChanged event will then fire whenever the value is changed in your databound controls (assuming they are two way bindings). So you can add a handler to that event and fire whatever command you like.

Comment: sorry, but this isn't what I'm after. FirstName and LastName are already implementing notification change. I want to bind a command to the specific multibinding used in XAMl